# Sinai’s Walk | Proof of basic result | how does the basic result follow from the two theorems in Sinai’s paper?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-walk

In “The Limiting Behavior of a One-dimensional Random Walk in a Random Medium” by Sinai, two theorems are proved in the last sections.

I fail to understand why the basic result follows from these theorems.

**Basic result**: It exists random variable $m(0)$ independent of the environment, such that $\forall\eta>0$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{\mathsf{X}_{n}}{\log^{2}n}-m(0)\right|>\eta\right)\longrightarrow_{n\rightarrow\infty}0.
\end{align}

**Theorem 1**: Let $M_{i1},M_{i2}\in\mathfrak{M}$ and $[M_{i1},M_{i2}]$ is a valley with the depth $d([M_{i1},M_{i2}])>1$ and $0\in[M_{i1},M_{i2}]$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\mathsf{X}_{m}\in[M_{i1}\log^{2}n,M_{i2}\log^{2}n],\forall 0\leq m\leq n\right)\to_{n\to\infty}1.
\end{align*}

**Theorem 2**: We consider an environment of $C_{n}$. Then for $\frac{1}{2}n\leq r\leq n$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\omega_{r}=m^{(0)}\right)\to_{n\to\infty}1
\end{align*}
uniformly for the environment of $C_{n}$.

Does anyone know? An heuristic approach is absolutely fine!

For more details see the paper by Sinai: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1127028

Comment: With some effort you can post [math notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to better express your Question.

Comment: Thanks @hardmath I’ve added the theorems.